# .htaccess file to block all IPs except 4 and always allow requests to /api/ for averyone

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to disallow all requests by

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !=67.x.x.x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

ErrorDocument 403 "<html><hea....
```

So the IP 67 should be allowed for all REQ - but the directory /api/ should be accessible for everyone.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You Can apply some of these directives.
Also, am thinking that your api is a directory

```
order deny,allow
deny from all 
allow from 222.333.444, 67.8.9.9 # ALLOWED IPS MUST BE SEPARATED BY COMMAS

<Directory /api>
# All access controls and authentication are disabled
# in this directory
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: It is not an actual folder, it is a controller in the framework

Answer (score 0):

To deny access to all but 4 specific ip addresses you can use a negative `RewriteCond` and regex pattern  to match against the **allowed** ip addresses  something like the following :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(ip1|ip2|ip3|ip4)
```

If you do not want your `/api` uri to be redirected to 403 you can exclude it in your Rewrite pattern so that the uri is available for both allowed and denied  ip addresses.

Full code :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !(ip1|ip2|ip3|ip4)
RewriteRule !api - [R=403,L]
```